# jQuery set style with variable

Tags: jquery

I want to set a CSS style using `$("#"+divId).css("display": "block");` but if I want to pass the style as a variable like `var display = "block";` to `$("#"+divId).css("display": display);` I get an error.

Comment: You should use `$("#"+divId).css("display", display);` instead of `$("#"+divId).css("display": display);`

Comment: And `$("#"+divId).css({"display": display});`

Comment: I'm voting to close this post because this is more of typo error.

Comment: Yes, I was following the accepted answer from another post, which is where the colon came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#"+divId).css("display": display);
```

to

```
$("#"+divId).css("display", display);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like

**For multiple css**

```
$("#"+divId).css({"display": display,'id':'newId'});
```

OR

```
$("#"+divId).css("display", display);
```